# Can Exp:resso Store handle recurring subscriptions

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

We're about to embark on a new project where we need to deploy a relatively simple shop, subscriptions, donations and the ability to offer subscribed members a percentage discount on all purchases in the shop. Users should also be able to opt to become members (paid subscription) at checkout. It would be great if this then facilitated an immediate percentage discount on products in their basket too.

I've been looking at Exp:resso Store (which I love because it embraces the 'products as entries' approach) but I'm not familiar enough with it to know if there's a way to use it to achieve all or any of the above.

Our client currently uses a very old version of X-cart and PayPal, as I understand it this creates formal subscriptions in PayPal.

Is it reasonable to expect that Store would be able to fulfil the requirements above or am I looking at the wrong product?

Comment: Nathan - we discourage open-ended questions which have no real "correct" answer here. I suggest you edit your question to ask something specific - e.g., "can product  do this specific thing I need for my e-commerce build". See: [what not to ask](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: No worries, will do. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point in time Exp:resso Store does not handle subscriptions of any kind natively. I'm needing subscriptions myself and have reached out to them for any possible help on this matter. They did explain to me that there are installations of store that are handling subscriptions however so it is possible to have store handle that function. It would be something that you would need to develop yourself or hire someone to do.

Cartthrob has a subscription module that you can purchase along with Cartthrob itself, which will run you $600 dollars combined. I would be weary though. I've used both e-commerce products and Cartthrob does have some advantages, but support has essentially dropped off in the past year. Store has had good support and is backed by a staff of people, i believe Cartthrob is maintained by one person it would seem.

I would recommend store as a shopping cart solution in almost all cases if it weren't for the fact that in your case it doesn't handle the main purpose that you need it for.

You might also look at a module called [Charge](http://dvt.ee/charge) if your needs are simple enough

Comment: Thanks Chris, some great guidance. I'd forgotten all about Charge and I think using this for Subscriptions and Store for Product sales might be the ideal solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can Exp:resso Store handle recurring subscriptions

No. There's a [feature request](https://exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) for it, but it would be a big undertaking to build so I wouldn't hold your breath.

> Users should also be able to opt to become members (paid subscription) at checkout. It would be great if this then facilitated an immediate percentage discount on products in their basket too.

Store does support creating discounts for specific member groups, so if you do use a different system to handle purchasing the subscriptions and maintaining which member group people belong in, Store would probably still be a good fit for selling your products.